# Setting ItemsPanel through ListBox style data triiggers when group style is set

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, .net-4.5

I have an ItemsControl which I have set a GroupStyle.

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.Panel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.Panel>
  </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

This style will arrange all the groups horizontally. Based on some condition I need to arrange the items inside the groups. For example, if some condition is met a panel for items in each group would be WrapPanel, otherwise it would be Canvas.

In case when there would be no GroupStyle set, I could do this:

```
<ListBox.Style>
  <Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeCondition}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I combine the two?

Comment: @N.J What benefit would MultiDataTrigger bring? There is only one condition.

Comment: *"Based on some condition"* - What exactly is this condition? Can you elaborate on exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the Properly

Comment: @MikeEason A condition is a state of the control that hosts the ListBox. For the purpose of this question it is not necessary to include this control also, it will just make things more complicated. If you want to test it in some scenario, you can bind it to the togglebutton's IsChecked. Whenevert button is checked, panel should be Canvas, otherwise StackPanel.